ngx-mat-timepicker is not giving same style, I don't know how to add theme styling
I'm following this article: https://dhutaryan.github.io/ngx-mat-timepicker/#/getting-started#theming
I'm getting different type of styling, the circle around the clock is missing and buttons on click color is missing. I'm sure I am lacking the Theming design of it.
Please guide me for how to add the theme styling for it to be same as in article. Give this a look: https://dhutaryan.github.io/ngx-mat-timepicker/#/getting-started#theming

angular ngx-mat-timepicker theme style guidance needed.

What version do you use? If 18.0.0 then try 18.0.1

This issue has been already fixed
